# Is it possible to detect whether a monitor attached to a Windows PC is actively displaying a certain input?

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, vnc, vesa

I'm developing a Windows application that supports remote displays through VNC. Normally the remote displays will be the only visual interface. However, there will be cases where a user will want to view the application with a physical monitor. If a physically attached monitor is connected *and* switched to a specific input (could be DVI or HDMI), I need to be able to detect that and turn off VNC. **Is it possible to detect whether an attached monitor is actively displaying a certain input?**

I know that I can get some information about the attached monitors with [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4) but nothing therein seems to quite match what I need. Is there perhaps some method exposed by the Windows API that could give me this information? Can the necessary information be determined from VESA/DDC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience developing a VNC application, but maybe a suggestion might start you off on the right path.

Download [wmiexplorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/)

1. Run the program
2. Here you can explorer different classes in WMI, which will be the lowest level I think you're going to get
3. Go to the Query tab and enter the query: `"select * from Win32_DesktopMonitor"`

I think this is the information you can use to figure out information about your monitors.  (I'm not sure what classes have information that relates to monitors)

In particular, check out [Availability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394122%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the Win32_DesktopMonitor class.

**Update**

Running this query on a remote machine Description and DeviceID and Name came back as "Default Monitor."  On my real machine, it came back as "Generic PnP Monitor" as well as had a `MonitorManufacturer` set, where as the remote machine didn't.  You could even go as far as comparing the queried monitor with `Screen` resolution or maybe `SystemName` returned in the query vs. the system name of the computer running the application.

Use the [ManagementObjectSearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to execute WMI queries.

**Edit**

You could also do the mapping/cross-checking of devices like the example shown [here](http://japrogbits.blogspot.com/2010/03/using-wmi-to-query-monitor-information.html) does.  Notice the `ClassGUID` is the same between MonitorDesktop and PnPEntity.